# Best way to declare intermediate variables in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, variables, optimization

I stumbled upon a piece of code I am using frequently which consists in doing arithmetic operations within a loop to update a quantity. The important bit is that I am using **intermediate quantity independent from the loop index**. I figured out two ways of writing it. In this mock example, I use scalars and vectors but I suppose this applies to virtually every quantity updated using a loop:

```
scalar coef = someComplicatedScalar;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
   vector someComplicatedVector;
   stuff[i] = someComplicatedScalar * someComplicatedVector;
}
```

or

```
scalar coef = someComplicatedScalar;
vector someComplicatedVector;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
   stuff[i] = someComplicatedScalar * someComplicatedVector;
}
```

During development, I mostly do the first one. I was wondering if it is worth moving from the first to the second implementation during code cleaning.
My concern is about optimisation because as C++ cannot create new variables at runtime and I am afraid it creates a bunch of useless copies.

Note: I am using a C++ framework hence the use of alternative classes.

Comment: *and I am afraid it creates a bunch of useless copies.* -- The compiler's optimizer probably can easily determine that `vector` is an invariant that can be moved outside of the loop.  You also need to ensure you are building an optimized version of the code, and not a "debug" or unoptimized version.

Comment: Looking at the code is not going to tell you much. You should profile both versions to see which one is better.

Comment: Prefer the seconf form with the variable outside the loop if the value does not change and for better clarity you might even want to declare that object `const` so that one immediatly know it won't change inside the loop (if is is somewhat more complex) and to prevent accidental changes during future maintenance.

Comment: To cigien: I am asking because I have loads of variables in this situation. This was how the code was when I took it over, and I did not pay much care into avoiding form 1 either.

to Phil1970: Thanks for the suggestion, although I can't declare most of these variables `const` because those bits of code I am talking about are part of a more complex system of loop (time stepping loops in a Solid Dynamics code if you're curious).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- being an invariant is not sufficient; in order for this optimization to be valid, the object's constructor and destructor must not have visible side effects. We don't know what this `vector` type does, but if, for example, its constructor counts the number of objects that have been created, then moving the object outside the loop changes the count, and is not a legal compiler optimization. It could, of course, be a valid user optimization.

Comment: @Pete Becker: It does actually do a similar counting through a game of references, so I shall consider this

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will automatically optimize your code if it find an expression or operation invariant of the loop.

But for the shake of explicit optimization you can put all the expressions and instantiation of local variables which are invariant of the loop outside of the loop.
This will be the well optimized code.

Comment: Be careful here. For built-in types (`int`, etc.) this is correct, because creating and destroying an `int` variable has no side effects. Compilers routinely hoist these guys to the top and create them once. But for user-defined types, constructing and destroying objects can have visible side effects, and moving such an object outside of the loop is not a valid optimization. Consider, for example, an object whose constructor counts the number of objects that have been created; moving the object outside the loop changes that count, and the result does not conform to the language definition.